# unprintable python unicode string

Tags: python, unicode, string-conversion, mojibake

I retrieved some exif info from an image and got the following:

```
{ ...
37510: u'D2\nArbeitsamt\n\xc3\x84nderungsbescheid'
...}
```

I expected it to be

```
{ ...
37510: u'D2\nArbeitsamt\nÄnderungsbescheid'
... }
```

I need to convert the value to a str, but i couldn't manage it to work. I always get something like (using python27)

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 14-15: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Any ideas how I can handle this?

UPDATE:

I tried it with python3 and there is now error thrown, but the result is now

```
{ ...
37510: 'D2\nArbeitsamt\nÃ\x84nderungsbescheid',
... }
```

which is still not the expected.

Comment: Python2 or Python3? It feels like I'm looking at Python2 code so I'll just go for it. You're looking to do `x[37510].encode('UTF-8')` or `x[37510].decode('UTF-8')`, I can never remember which way it is. The default encoding in terms of trying to interpreter strings is the ASCII table instead of guessing which encoding the string has. There for the developer need to do this for the language, rather than the language doing this for you.

Comment: are you using python2?

Comment: its python2, @Torxed tried both variants with no success

Comment: I'm not even sure what to blame here... is python 2's unicode handling the problem, or is the EXIF library at fault for producing that data in the first place...?

Comment: I used PIL as the exif reader and I am quite sure that this is fine. May it be that the creator of the exif data (gthumb) used another encoding than utf8?

Comment: I don't think the EXIF specification actually specifies which text encoding to use. In fact the whole exif ecosystem is a horrible mess and device vendors don't seem to care much about standardization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be utf8 which was incorrectly decoded as latin1 and then placed in a unicode string. You can use `.encode('iso8859-1')` to reverse the incorrect decoding.

```
>>> my_dictionary = {37510: u'D2\nArbeitsamt\n\xc3\x84nderungsbescheid'}
>>> print(my_dictionary[37510].encode('iso8859-1'))
D2
Arbeitsamt
Änderungsbescheid
```

You can print it out just fine now, but you might then also decode it as unicode, so it ends up with the correct type for further processing:

```
>>> type(my_dictionary[37510].encode('iso8859-1'))
<type 'str'>
>>> print(my_dictionary[37510].encode('iso8859-1').decode('utf8'))
D2
Arbeitsamt
Änderungsbescheid
>>> type(my_dictionary[37510].encode('iso8859-1').decode('utf8'))
<type 'unicode'>
```

Comment: If you have input text with incorrect or unknown encoding, there's a python library called [ftfy](https://ftfy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) which does a quite decent job fixing most typical encoding mixups. It's useful for parsing text data embedded in exif, since other programs might encode strings as utf8 instead of latin1 (8859-1).

Comment: By the way, this is not latin1 (iso 8859-1). It seems to be utf8 which was incorrectly decoded as latin1. `.encode('iso8859-1')` reverses the incorrect decoding. I'm not sure if `print()` will always get the utf8 encoding right. I suspect it depends on the system locale setting. This is something that has been changed a lot between python 2 and python 3.

Comment: Thank you Håken Lid I have improved the answer.